# Laravel backpack "not understanding about user login role and permissions"

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I am analyzing Laravel's backpack trial package, I am not sure about user role and permission.

I am seeing in database **model_has_roles** table

```
role_id  |       model_type          | model_id
---------|---------------------------|----------
   1     |  App\Models\BackpackUser  |    3
   2     |  App\Models\BackpackUser  |    4
```

and **model_has_permissions** table

```
permission_id |    model_type            |  model_id
--------------|--------------------------|-------------
      1       |  App\Models\BackpackUser |     3
      2       |  App\Models\BackpackUser |     4
```

**I want to ask that what is model and how it is work?**

Answer (score 1):

[Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#introduction) are PHP classes that help you with database input/output, in a more object-oriented manner. It's how you interact with your database.

Please note you should have a reasonable understanding of Laravel before using Backpack. If you are not familiar with how Laravel works, you'll have a difficult time understanding how Backpack works. I recommend the free [Laravel from scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018) series on Laracasts.